# Reading a file with parameter

Tags: python-3.x

I have a usecase to read a text file with parameters. Parameters should be replaced with commandline argument which we provide as input while running the script.

Example:

```
This is python which is #param1 language.
Python is #param2 in machine learning.

#param1: good
#param2: rich

Output:
This is python which is good language.
Python is rich in machine learning.
```

I can open the file in "Read" mode but how i can replace the argument programmatically?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: We need more information. How many parameters are there, for instance. And are they always written like `#param` in the file?

Comment: Can you show the code from your attempt and describe exactly how it's failing?

Comment: Show us what you have done so far and we can help on top of it :)

Comment: My scope is, I need to read a file & pass the content of file as argument to the python script i dint start with my code yet but wanted to get an idea/solution. If someone has already tried, pls throw some light.